# CarouFredSel Image Links

Tags: jquery, image, hyperlink, caroufredsel

I am using CarouFredSel for a website I am designing, however I encountered a problem...everything works as expected until I try and link the images to a url.

The `script` looks like:

```
$(function() {
    /* Homepage */
    $("#slide-image > div").carouFredSel({
        auto: false,
        items: {
            visible: 2
        },
        next: "#next",
        prev: "#prev",
        scroll: {
            easing: "quadratic",
            items: 1
        },
        width: "100%"
    });
});
```

and the `code` looks like:

```
<div id="slide-image">
    <div>
        <a href="www.example.com"><img src="images/example.jpg"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help is appreciated :)

Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out!!

As I was looking around I discovered that on the CarouFredSel website they had some tips and tricks (http://caroufredsel.dev7studios.com/support/tips-and-tricks.php) and in the middle of the page they document "Use block-elements that float left"...right underneath that the `HTML` code they use is linked...so I just copied that and presto!

So, now my `script` looks like:

```
$(function() {
    /* Homepage */
    $("#slide-image").carouFredSel({
        auto: false,
        items: {
            visible: 2
        },
        next: "#next",
        prev: "#prev",
        scroll: {
            easing: "quadratic",
            items: 1
        },
        width: "100%"
    });
});
```

and the `code` looks like:

```
<div class="slide-image">
    <div id="slide-image">
        <a href="www.example.com"><img src="images/example.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="clear">
        <!-- -->
    </div>
</div>
```

The major things that changed was:

- I gave the inner div an ID, which caused my main function to change as well
- I am clearing the float, which is a little hard to see because I didn't post my css (although it's the same as the example at: http://caroufredsel.dev7studios.com/support/tips-and-tricks.php)

Other than than the code is exactly the same as what I posted originally...glad it was an easy fix - hope this helps someone!!

Thanks,
Josh